# How to customize the headers of a RadGridView?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid

I am creating a WPF project using Telerik controls. I need to create a GridView to display some data, only the column headings should be different colors.
I have this but does not work:

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="dtgResum" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,10,10" 
                      RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" 
                      IsReadOnly="True" 
                      ShowGroupPanel="False"      
                      CanUserFreezeColumns="False" 
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                      CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                      CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                      IsFilteringAllowed="True" 
                      ColumnWidth="*" 
                      AlternationCount="2" 
                      AlternateRowBackground="#EFEFEF">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colEstatus" Header="ESTATUS" Background="#538DD5"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colId" Header="ID" Background="#D9D9D9"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colMza" Header="MZA" Background="#D9D9D9"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colLot" Header="LOT" Background="#D9D9D9"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colNo" Header="No" Background="#D9D9D9"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colInt" Header="INT" Background="#D9D9D9"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colEdif" Header="EDIF" Background="#D9D9D9"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="col1" Header="SOME LONG HEADER" Background="#538DD5"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="col2" Header="OTHER LONG HEADER" Background="#538DD5"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="col3" Header="THIS IS A LONG HEADER OF THE COLUMN" Background="#D86B0A"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="col4" Header="THIS IS A LONG HEADER OF THE COLUMN" Background="#D86B0A"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="col5" Header="THIS IS A LONG HEADER OF THE COLUMN" Background="#D86B0A"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="col6" Header="THIS IS A LONG HEADER OF THE COLUMN" Background="#D86B0A"/>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

The designer gives me this result and rather ugly:

[image]

And I need the headers have different colors and can show a lot of text, as in the following image::

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to customize the style of the column headers. See telerik's documentation on this topic: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/styles-and-templates/styling-column-headers

Comment: I've never done anything like this, so I find it hard to understand how to create my own style from scratch. Will you have any examples that illustrate how I do it ?, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property `HeaderCellStyle` that can be used to set the style of the Header cell for each column. You can find your theme's XAML within the install folder. For a minor tweak, like background and font size, you could just use a 'based on' style and change those properties, rather than editing the Template.

Ex:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colEstatus" Header="ESTATUS">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.HeaderCellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewHeaderCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:GridViewHeaderCell}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#538DD5" />
        </Style>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.HeaderCellStyle>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: I've never done anything like this, so I find it hard to understand how to create my own style from scratch. Will you have any examples that illustrate how I do it ?, please

Comment: @Richard - I added an example. You can find the full xaml styles in the install directory if deeper re-styling is required.

Comment: @Richard - But to be honest, if you've never done WPF control styling, I wouldn't recommend the Telerik controls as a first introduction. They often have many 'hard-coded' / non-standard gotchas.

Comment: When attempting to test the example, throws me this error:
**It does not recognize or can not access the member "HeaderColumnStyle"**

Comment: @Richard fixed the code, was meant to be `HeaderCellStyle`.

Comment: Yes, it works well; now, how I can put more text in one column and this is shown as in the picture I put?

Comment: You may need to add in the `BasedOn=...` code from the edit above. For changing font and text wrapping, you should explore more about WPF styling.

Comment: I'll take that into account, I really appreciate your time.